# Bluetooth tethering

Tags: bluetooth, embedded

I have Quectel M66 modem which is bluetooth enabled. I need some hints about how can I provide internet to my embedded device (which has M66 as a peripheral) using Android or iOS, or other device which supports bluetooth tethering.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Android has that feature by default. Take a look at this link:

https://www.androidpit.com/share-wifi-over-bluetooth

I believe you can just approach the tethering device as a wifi acces point following the above guide.

This link sheds some light on choosing what tethering approach is appropriate:

http://m.pocketnow.com/2014/03/21/tethering-methods

My initial thought was "why would you want to tether through Bluetooth?" but looking at the power consumption, it might be a good choice for an embedded system, or if Wi-Fi is not available on the board.